# Discharging patient under influence of anesthesia without an emergency contact to bring patient home

Tags: united-states, liability, medical

If a healthcare facility discharges a patient who is still under the influence of anesthesia after a medical procedure without an emergency contact to bring the patient home and the patient walked out the facility and fell after tripping on the concrete and injured himself badly, can the patient sue the healthcare facility? If so, what kind of lawsuit can the patient file? Also, what is the liability of the healthcare facility?

Comment: Depends on countless details. What did the doctors know, what should they have known, did the patient sign any disclaimers, did the the patient *demand* to leave ...